# Bash - how to expand a variable and single quote it to pass to sudo

Tags: bash

## Question

How to expand a shell variable, single quote it, then pass it to sudo?

### Attempt

This does not work.

```
key="some string including special characters"
file='/home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys'

sudo -i -u ansible grep -q -E "'"${key}"'" $file
```

It is not working.

```
 sudo -i -u ansible cat /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

> hoge
>   h oge
>   hoge

```
key='h oge'
sudo -i -u ansible grep -E "'"$key"'" $file
```

> grep: oge': No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never thought I'd say this, but [Use Fewer Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) (trademark pending). This should work fine:

```
sudo -i -u ansible grep -q -E "$key" "$file"
```

Basically, you only have to provide syntactic quotes for the literal code (unless you are doing something `eval`).

---

If you have characters in `key` which have a special meaning **in a regular expression** that is an entirely different problem. In that case use `grep -q -F "$key" "$file"` to search for a literal string rather than an extended regular expression.

Comment: The important thing here is that `sudo` (correctly!) does not run the shell, so (after your immediate shell, as always) there is no quoting to do in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Had not fully understood how sudo was designed.

Comment: This is not specific to `sudo`. In a very real way you don't need to use more than one set of syntactic quotes when writing shell scripts. It's only when you then evaluate strings as code (by using for example `eval`) that there should be multiple levels of syntactic quotes.